# Hide Picklist value on profile

Tags: picklist, profile

I have one pick list field with 5 value on custom object. Now i wanted to hide 2 value out of 5 value one of my profile "ABC".

I have created one record type for that and hide that value and assign to new page layout and also set this in page layout assignment and set also this record type as default on respected profile.

Now the problem is when i create records then it's showing me 3 value that is correct as per the above settings but while i referring to old records with this profile then it's showing me all the 5 picklist value instead of that 3 value.

Please suggest how can i hide that value from the old records.

Thanks in advance for the resolution

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like to me that you need to update the recordtypeID field on all the old records and that should fix it. You can use data loader to mass export and then update the records.

Comment: thanks for the update....can it be possible to update record ID without update the recordTypeID to update the picklist value

Comment: So the pick list is just a UI thing. IE once you have set the picklist value even if you change the recordtypeID to something else the picklist value won't change on the record. If the record picklist value no longer exists in the picklist (Ie because you have taken it off that particular recordtype) the records value will still be shown in the picklist for that particular record. But if you change the value on the record to a different picklist value you won't be able to go back to the old value on the record. If that all makes sense :) but test it first to see.